# Minecraft stopped working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Today after installing some drivers from nvidia, My sister tried to play some minecraft when she got this:

```
[14:12:53 INFO]: Launching game
[14:12:53 INFO]: Unpacking natives to C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11.2\1.11.2-natives-3354877165086
[14:12:53 INFO]: Launching in C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
[14:12:53 INFO]: Half command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Dos.name=Windows 10 -Dos.version=10.0 -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11.2\1.11.2-natives-3354877165086 -cp C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\netty\1.6\netty-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.24\authlib-1.5.24.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.10.11\realms-1.10.11.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\7.0.12_mojang\fastutil-7.0.12_mojang.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11.2\1.11.2.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main
[14:12:53 INFO]: Looking for orphaned versions to clean up...
[14:12:53 INFO]: Looking for old natives & assets to clean up...
[14:12:55 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code -1073740791)
[14:12:55 INFO]: Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
[14:12:55 INFO]: Deleting C:\Users\Kids\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.11.2\1.11.2-natives-3354877165086
```

I've tried uninstalling minecraft, java, and reinstalling nvidia drivers. same error. I can confirm that games still work on my system, just not minecraft. does anyone know why?

```
[14:12:49 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.6.76 (through bootstrap 100) started on windows...
[14:12:49 INFO]: Current time is Feb 4, 2017 2:12:49 PM
[14:12:49 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 10'
[14:12:49 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.version') == '10.0'
[14:12:49 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
[14:12:49 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_25'
[14:12:49 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
[14:12:49 INFO]: System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'
[14:12:49 INFO]: proxy == DIRECT
[14:12:49 INFO]: JFX is already initialized
[14:12:49 INFO]: Refreshing local version list...
[14:12:49 INFO]: Refreshing remote version list...
[14:12:50 INFO]: Refresh complete.
```

here is more info.

Comment: Try rolling back to a different nVidia driver.

Comment: Wow an exit code of -1073740791. I have never seen such a lengthy exit code before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you need to go back to an older version of the Nvidia driver. Or update to a newer update from Nvidia solves the issue.

See the [Minecraft bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MC-112780) for the same error code, which has now been resolved. I've included the suggested fix below.

> Download the latest **driver version 378.66** (or later)